# Bug in pydicom function

Tags: python, pydicom

I wanted to work with pydicom for processing dicom images. Unfortunately I get the error

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dicom/dataset.py", line 372, in _pixel_data_numpy
    raise TypeError(msg % (numpy_format, self.PixelRepresentation,
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'numpy_format' referenced before assignment
```

in the function

```
def _pixel_data_numpy(self):
"""Return a NumPy array of the pixel data.

NumPy is a numerical package for python. It is used if available.

:raises TypeError: if no pixel data in this dataset.
:raises ImportError: if cannot import numpy.

"""
if 'PixelData' not in self:
    raise TypeError("No pixel data found in this dataset.")

if not have_numpy:
    msg = "The Numpy package is required to use pixel_array, and numpy could not be imported.\n"
    raise ImportError(msg)

# determine the type used for the array
need_byteswap = (self.is_little_endian != sys_is_little_endian)

# Make NumPy format code, e.g. "uint16", "int32" etc
# from two pieces of info:
#    self.PixelRepresentation -- 0 for unsigned, 1 for signed;
#    self.BitsAllocated -- 8, 16, or 32
format_str = '%sint%d' % (('u', '')[self.PixelRepresentation],
                          self.BitsAllocated)
try:
    numpy_format = numpy.dtype(format_str)
print numpy_format
except TypeError:
print "Data type not understood by NumPy!"
print format_str
    msg = ("Data type not understood by NumPy: "
           "format='%s', PixelRepresentation=%d, BitsAllocated=%d")
    raise TypeError(msg % (numpy_format, self.PixelRepresentation,
                    self.BitsAllocated))

# Have correct Numpy format, so create the NumPy array
arr = numpy.fromstring(self.PixelData, numpy_format)

# XXX byte swap - may later handle this in read_file!!?
if need_byteswap:
    arr.byteswap(True)  # True means swap in-place, don't make a new copy
# Note the following reshape operations return a new *view* onto arr, but don't copy the data
if 'NumberOfFrames' in self and self.NumberOfFrames > 1:
    if self.SamplesPerPixel > 1:
        arr = arr.reshape(self.SamplesPerPixel, self.NumberOfFrames, self.Rows, self.Columns)
    else:
        arr = arr.reshape(self.NumberOfFrames, self.Rows, self.Columns)
else:
    if self.SamplesPerPixel > 1:
        if self.BitsAllocated == 8:
            arr = arr.reshape(self.SamplesPerPixel, self.Rows, self.Columns)
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError("This code only handles SamplesPerPixel > 1 if Bits Allocated = 8")
    else:
        arr = arr.reshape(self.Rows, self.Columns)
return arr
```

When I print the variable `format_str`, I get `uint12`. Unfortunately I am not able to solve this bug. Is there anything I can do for solving that?
Even if I remove all `print` commands (I added them for debug) I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here.  First, a bug in pydicom: in raising the error, it is incorrectly using `numpy_format`, which is undefined.  It should use `format_str`.  I'll add an issue to correct this.

The second problem is that the file claims to have BitsAllocated of 12, which is very unusual. DICOM files typically have 12-bit pixels values but use 16-bits per pixel in the file.

You can check what it is really allocating by comparing the `Rows` and `Columns` to the size of the pixel data.  For a single frame image (below example uses pydicom's CT_small.dcm sample file):

```
>>> len(ds.PixelData)
32768
>>> ds.Rows * ds.Columns * 2  # 2 bytes for 16-bit allocation
32768
```

If the image has multiple frames then you would have to multiply the number of frames as well. Similarly for `SamplesPerPixel`.

If the size of pixel data matches as above using 2 bytes per pixel, then you can correct your problem by setting `ds.BitsAllocated` to 16 before asking for `pixel_array`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the code is meant to be formatted like this:

```
try:
    numpy_format = numpy.dtype(format_str)
    print numpy_format
except TypeError:
    print "Data type not understood by NumPy!"
    print format_str
    msg = ("Data type not understood by NumPy: "
           "format='%s', PixelRepresentation=%d, BitsAllocated=%d")
    raise TypeError(msg % (numpy_format, self.PixelRepresentation,
                    self.BitsAllocated))
```

In the `try` block, `numpy_format` is assigned a value. If `numpy.dtype(format_str)` throws a `TypeError`, it goes straight to the `except` block without binding a value to `numpy_format`. This means when `numpy_format` is referenced again when raising the `TypeError`, it throws a `UnboundLocalError` as it was never bound in the first place.